# outside click is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a button. If i click that button one popup will open in Navbar. I am using ui-bootstrap for this.

If I click outside the popup is not closing.

- I wrote window.onclick function to achieve this. It is working.
- But My problem is, If I click button popup will open. If I select any value in dropdown, on top of that one more popup will open.
- So If I select any dropdwon value on the second dropdown, the first dropdown is automatically closing.
- My need is, When I click button dropdown should open. and If I click outside the dropdown close.
- If I select any value from dropdown, the dropdown should stable. It should not go off. Only when I click outside that time only it should go.

```html
<button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="showFilterBtn" ng-click="showDropdown($event)">
<img src="assets/images/filterIcon.png">&nbsp&nbspFilter <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
      <div>{{filter.filterObject}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

```js
window.onclick = function() {
   $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
}
```

If I click button, the dropdown should not go.

Comment: which component you are using for popup??

Comment: your code snippet is not working. can you please put working example.

Comment: Check whether this link helps - https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/25/angular-6-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do, again this is not ideal way to do it, since we have little data provided by you, I can only think of this kind of fix :)

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('dropdown-menu') &&!$(event.target).parents().hasClass('dropdown-menu')) {
         $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    }
});
```

**EDIT 1**

Just add a parent div and keep a unique class for dropdown-parents which you don't want to close
suppose class name is `dropdown-select`

and then just edit the condition like this

```
if (!$(event.target).hasClass('dropdown-select') &&!$(event.target).parents().hasClass('dropdown-select')) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much kenny. If i select any value in second dropdown, the first dropdown is automatically closing. Is this possible to keep the first chart. It should only close while clicking outside. Not on dropdown selection

Comment: Edited the answer. Let me know, if this resolves your issue

Comment: if (!$(event.target).hasClass('lui-popover-container') &&!$(event.target).parents().hasClass('lui-popover-container')) {

Comment: This is my second Dropdown, If I use this, while clicking outside "dropdown-menu" is not hiding.

Answer (score -1):

You should add an extension to the jquery library then add this script since you are using javascript

```
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
        });
    </script>
```